# Filling the first plot with plotyy

Tags: matlab, plot

I am using a plotyy and i Need to fill the area of the plot on the left y-axis. and the other plot(i.e. on the righzt axis) should be a line graph and should not be filled. I have the following code:  `

```
subplot(2,1,2);
[ax,h1,h2]=plotyy(Messwerte.(Messwerte.VehV_v.time),...
Messwerte.VehV_v.value,Messwerte.(Messwerte.ftead_w.time),...
Messwerte.ftead_w.value,@plot,@area);
set(h1, 'LineWidth', 3);
set(h2, 'FaceColor', 'k');
%uistack(ax(1));
set(ax(1),'xtick',[0:500:2000])
set(ax(1),'ylim',[0 140],'ytick',[0:20:140])
set(ax(2),'xtick',[0:500:2000])
set(ax(2),'ylim',[0 14],'ytick',[0:2:14])
ylabel('Fahrzeuggeschwindigkeit')
grid on
```

`

- With this code, automatically the plot on the right axis gets filled but i Need to fill the graph on the left axis .
- I tried to use uistack(ax(1)) as well but it didnt work out neither i could understand ist use.  Could anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `set` commands

```
set(h1, 'LineWidth', 3);
set(h2, 'FaceColor', 'k');
```

set the appearance of the plots. Currently, you're setting the line width of the left plot to 3, and the plot symbols of the right plot to filled. It seems you want to switch `h1` and `h2`. Note that `get(h1)` reveals a list of properties that you caould also set.

Comment: Hello @Jonas I tried switching the handles but i recieve an error :  ´´Error using graph2d.lineseries/set
The name 'FaceColor' is not an accessible property for an instance of class
'lineseries'.

Error in Measurement (line 30)
set(h1, 'FaceColor', 'k');´´

Comment: @AakashSehgal: sorry, you also need to switch `@area`, `@plot`.